# How can I prepend lines that don't start with certain keywords?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, python

I'm modifying a bunch of python files and I need to prepend every variable declaration with 'self.'. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

From this:

```
class testClass(parentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        parentClass.__init__(self)

        flag1               = 0  
        flag2               = 1    

        array =           (0,
                           1,
                           2)
```

To this:

```
class testClass(parentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        parentClass.__init__(self)

        self.flag1               = 0  
        self.flag2               = 1    

        self.array =           (0,
                                1,
                                2)
```

I'm familiar with `sed` but I'm not sure how to prepend lines that don't match multiple strings/numbers. I.g. prepend line if it doesn't match the following patterns: `^'def'` or `^'import'` or `^'parentClass'` or `^[0-9]`. Any guidance would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Is this only about `__init__` methods or do you want to prepend `self.` in all class methods?

Answer (score 0):

This little perl one-liner will attempt to restrict the substitution to the `__init__` method

```
perl -pe '
    if (/^\s* def \s+ __init__/x) {
        $start = 1;
    }
    elsif ($start) {
        s{ (\w+) (?=\s+=) }{self.$1}x;
        /^\s* (class | def) \b/x and $start = 0;
    }
' file.py
```

Or, the same logic in awk

```
awk '
    $1 == "def" && $2 ~ /^__init__/ {start = 1; print; next}
    start && /^[[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+)[[:blank:]]*=/ {
        $0 = gensub(/[[:alnum:]_]+/, "self.\\0", 1)
    }
    {print}
    $1 == "def" || $1 == "class" {start = 0}
' file.py
```

Comment: I'm assuming python variable names consist of letters, numbers and underscore. Please update my regex if I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lines you want to apply the variable prepend to always have the `=` sign form you specified, this `sed` one-liner should work.

```
$ cat myfile.py 
class testClass(parentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        parentClass.__init__(self)

        flag1               = 0  
        flag2               = 1    

        array =           (0,
                           1,
                           2)
$ sed -e 's/\(^\s\+\)\(\w\+\)\(\s*=\)/\1self\.\2\3/g' myfile.py 
class testClass(parentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        parentClass.__init__(self)

        self.flag1               = 0  
        self.flag2               = 1    

        self.array =           (0,
                           1,
                           2)
```

That horrible looking regular expression is looking for lines that start with an alphanumeric string (ignoring whitespace), then have some spaces before an equal sign.  It prepends `self.` to the variable.